# Echarts responsive Grid and Legend

Tags: echarts

I am looking for a way to get the bounding box of the echarts (SVGRenderer) legend item to get the height.

I want to avoid an overlapping of legend and grid item.

Comment: I dont know if there is a simple way but you could take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/master/src/component/legend/LegendView.ts). As far as I could tell from a short glance the function `layoutInner` seems to calculate the bounding box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to get the position and dimension of the legend item. [Related question in Github](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/16480)

I am using LitV2 for the wrapping WebComponent. After finishing the rendering of the component I trigger a measurement function, which extracts the necessary information and updates the grid offset in the bottom.

```js
    get legendBoundingBox() {
     const legendModel = this.chart.getModel().getComponent('legend');
     const legendView = this.chart.getViewOfComponentModel(legendModel);
     this.legendHeight = legendView.group.getBoundingRect().height;
     //this.options.grid.bottom = this.legendHeight; // Update chart options
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your legend to not overlap with your graph ever you could specify a position outside of the grid for the legend:

```js
option = {
    grid: {
        top: '6%',
        ...
    },
    legend: {
        bottom: '96%',
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

This way the legend will get pushed out of the window instead of into the graph if it gets too big. I dont think this is the better alternative but maybe it satisfies your needs.

I adjusted one of the echarts online [examples](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-stack&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAG0iAXMmuhgE4QDmFApqYQOQCGAHhAM70A0x6L7ACsAjQwtQqhIkwATxDUGbABaMAJsADu9HrAC-xHd3TZqNaCvEAjYGEwBbBgE4AbAFJ6B4hXLmik4wDMwBgBmN0MScgpFINh6ABYw7SsbYHtY0K5tTAJY10zJAGMYMEZhABlGC2psQjBSAFdqfXDmAEFWNkIAbW0JSQxZeViCxlEKYFJpfP6VUcZu-gBZGC5YgBVG1foAdWoVLbXFeq2AMXItgGVRy_roegBdbT10e_DpdvZu3u10GTkGABujGwmyexFexDYtAg1E6sB6kj6kmgjFsQ3oABEIKRqAUwNNJH90RZGKQCSRqLYQMo2J9fP10P5gAV6nD6FDyLCtAyPAzZiVusEAEwABk4sGCwvFwRFAEZpcE4tKHGKJTLpaLHpJeSQkSQUWiGABRWylbDk36DBgksnhSRsEoFADWDFa-ztFKpNLpeskTJZbI5MI4P10HvQ_Pm8NlovFsqlsFlcrjivFKvFQvVsCFSa1JB16F9sAN6IAqtAoHA3RxwwN_rEbRbYA7GM7Xe7Q5TqYxaXCi4zmayFNCuaGCyRI90hbHEwAOIVxhzy7Op7PptWq4K5p4eoslhgANQgKmowFg1abROtpKbLbbsTdTa73r7oYHAeHnJDPNrk-jAFZVUzBds2TRN_yVRN10lVU4m3bVd1DfdYguahSQKRRYCNaAKGEahLytBsb1_OZulnJwQKTWVZzTJxIKTIUnDjJwAHYHGYkVVVlf8WJFCEGWfHsfTfWB_SHWIg1HH9Q1NUgnTKPDxBE7A8IuGRjCUhlCUI-hZiUPZuS08dJD_LouiQOt0VsYR6DDZBLIYU1mFsnR7jzbUd2-BlkPoAAhUoVGOWsryI21QxtbZjzARRCH_Ws7xdFC0NIDCsJwvCny9ITXy00TB0DEdv36YzYFMijVRYhNeOXSr6JFddZXjLiYz4zzESQ1F0QAcSwChjAI-t6EbeLHUS-hUPQzDsNw6B8NrQTe00rSxIKr9DIQ0NTJalNKLA-NIKFddMyAzU2t1DrDViXzhAoAbiWI0MEoYCaUqm9LZsy7tFvpBkVs_YN1vzEiBXhJwKpAliavohqs0a1qNva7zOoYAB5aLaBrUMQqGh6GSepLJrSma5s7LLvv7PKPwkwrAfQEqypA-c02XWc6vYxMkzjU6PJeFAdAAbiAA) to showcase the effect. You can test the behaviour by resizing the browser window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not what I asked for. I want a responsive solution, for which I need to capture the actual height of the legend. Found a solution and will post it.

Comment: Thats right. I just wanted to provide an alternative in the absence of any better ideas from my side.